# QT+Android+Lib = VFP Error

Tags: android, c++, qt, fpu, d2xx

im currently developing an Qt App, which uses FTDIs D2xx Library. My status is that I can compile and run the programm under Windows, Linux and an embedded Linux (Odroid, with self-compiled cross compile Qt).

But I'm struggling with Android (Qt's stock libs). I'm using the same ARMv7 lib as for the Odroid-Build, but now I have some trouble with the FPU, I think. So the error is:

> libftd2xx.so uses VFP register arguments, output does not

FTDI says that their lib uses HardFP (SP and DP) with VFP registers (VFPv3-D16).
When I change the qmake.conf for my android device like so:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mhard-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove
```

The linker spills errors for each .o of my project.

So my question is: How can I tell Qt that the whole project should use hard-FP? Or did I miss anything else?

Thanks in advance,
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to surpress the error:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--no-warn-mismatch
```

But now the other problem is that FTDI built the library with

> -hash-style=gnu

instead of

> -hash-style=sysv

and therefore it's not usable under Android, afaik :(